# Azure Database for MySQL servers: Location: service not available in this location for your subscription

Tags: mysql, database, service, geolocation, azure-sql

I am trying to create an Azure DB MySQL server and under location I keep getting this error.

" service not available in this location for your subscription."

Could you guide me what needs to be selected here?

Answer (score 2):

Please do convey which region you are trying to create your resources. There are some limitations that have been implemented at a subscription level to ensure service availability for Covid-19 essential services and Workloads related to this global pandemic. You could try Southeast Asia region, as customers have been successful in deploying non-critical services to this region without issue.

You may find further details regarding this here - [Microsoft cloud services continuity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/)

Regards

Navtej S